# how to solve unexpected token using MySQL Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Im getting below error

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:unexpected token values: values near line 1, column 161 .

```
[insert into shop_information(storeName, ownername, license, email, dlnumber, gst, pan, pincode, phonenumber, mobile, fax, cst, phone, district, state, country) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
```

Comment: Post the method code .

Comment: This is My Code

Comment: Maybe you're trying to execute native sql but using the hibernate method that creates JPQL/HQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
session.createSQLQuery(SQL_QUERY);
```

not

```
session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
```

HQL only supports insert from another table.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Entity properties_list select_statement.
```

If you wan't to use standard insert statement like

```
INSERT INTO Table properties_list values ( :vals)
```

you need

```
session.createSQLQuery(SQL_QUERY)
```

**Edit, to answer the comment:**

I think that the parameters are 0-based, so try to start the parameters from 0:

```
query.setParameter(0,storeName);
query.setParameter(1,ownerName);
etc...
```

However the better way is to use named parameters:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
  .createSQLQuery("update table set field = 1 where id = :id")
  .setParameter("id", someId)
  .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Getting this error...org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 17 @Evgeni Dimitrov

Comment: Again getting error...  java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
        im using this type  query.setParameter(0,storeName);

Comment: There are two terminating operators `executeQuery()` when execute a select sattement and `executeUpdate()` when execute insert, update, etc.

Comment: im using this same one sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
  .createSQLQuery("update table set field = 1 where id = :id")
  .setParameter("id", someId)
  .executeUpdate(); but getting error org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [storeName]